# Definite article use when writing about global population?

Tags: british-english, definite-articles

This is the first sentence in my work.

> Steadily ageing global population is leading to a crisis of noncommunicable diseases.

In most cases, the first mentioning is not preceded by a definite article. However, is this case an exception as there is only known "global population" for us? Therefore, the sentence should start with a definite article?

> The steadily ageing global population is leading to a crisis of noncommunicable diseases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

For humankind, there' only one known steadily ageing global population.

An alternative: Use the definitive article to shift some emphasis away from the sentence subject over to the object.  Example: Steadily ageing global population is leading to the crisis of noncommunicable diseases.

You're the writer. Depends on what you're trying to tell me, as the listener, to emphasize in your speech or written communication.